# 'react-native init' error : npm ERR! Command failed: git fetch -a origin

Tags: npm, react-native

An error has occurred while I trying to initialize a react-native project by: `react-native init awesomeProject`:

```
Installing react-native package from npm...
`npm install --save react-native` failed
```

Then I run this npm command manually , the errors looks like happen here:

```
npm verb afterAdd /Users/mc-zone/.npm/joi/6.9.1/package/package.json not in flight; writing
npm verb afterAdd /Users/mc-zone/.npm/joi/6.9.1/package/package.json written
npm ERR! git fetch -a origin (git://github.com/facebook/react.git) fatal: Unable to create temporary file '/Users/mc-zone/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-facebook-react-git-baa2986b/./objects/pack/tmp_pack_XXXXXX': Permission denied
npm ERR! git fetch -a origin (git://github.com/facebook/react.git) fatal: index-pack failed
npm verb about to build /Users/mc-zone/_dev/rn/node_modules/react-native
npm verb unlock done using /Users/mc-zone/.npm/_locks/react-native-ce52a7d7697a2d98.lock for /Users/mc-zone/_dev/rn/node_modules/react-native
npm verb stack Error: Command failed: git fetch -a origin
npm verb stack fatal: Unable to create temporary file '/Users/mc-zone/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-facebook-react-git-baa2986b/./objects/pack/tmp_pack_XXXXXX': Permission denied
npm verb stack fatal: index-pack failed
npm verb stack
npm verb stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:203:12)
npm verb stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
npm verb stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
npm verb stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:818:16)
npm verb stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
npm verb cwd /Users/mc-zone/_dev/rn
npm ERR! Darwin 14.3.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/mc-zone/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/bin/node" "/Users/mc-zone/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/bin/npm" "install" "react-native" "--save"
npm ERR! node v4.2.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7
npm ERR! code 128

npm ERR! Command failed: git fetch -a origin
npm ERR! fatal: Unable to create temporary file '/Users/mc-zone/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-facebook-react-git-baa2986b/./objects/pack/tmp_pack_XXXXXX': Permission denied
npm ERR! fatal: index-pack failed
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm verb exit [ 1, true ]
```

Seems to be a permission problem, I also use `sudo chown -R $USER ~/.npm` still not working.

And this `npm install` is excuted by `react-native-cli` so I can't add the `sudo` command to `npm`  (`sudo react-native init` still can't work )

How can I resolve this?

========

Other infomation:

System: Mac OS X 10.10.3

`npm` is installed by `nvm` when install `node`.

`nvm` is installed by `brew`.

```
$ npm -v 
2.14.7
$ node -v
v4.2.1
```

And there is my folders permissions (want to init application in `_dev`):

```
drwxrwxrwx  521 mc-zone  staff   17714 10 17 19:20 .npm
-rw-------    1 mc-zone  staff      56 10 17 17:01 .npmrc
drwxrwxrwx    5 mc-zone  staff     170 10 17 16:57 .nvm
drwxrwxrwx    4 mc-zone  staff     136 10 16 23:15 _dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by giving or taking the permissions in the installed folders:

```
➜  ~  sudo chmod 774 ProjectFolder/*
➜  ~  sudo chown Username ProjectFolder/*
➜  ~  sudo chmod 774 .babel.json 
➜  ~  sudo chown Username .babel.json
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a couple of step to create fresh project CRNA and run from expo.**

> step1: if you already install crna then skip this step.
>   npm install -g create-react-native-app
>
> step2: create-react-native-app AwesomeProject
>
> step3: cd AwesomeProject
>
> step4: npm start or yarn start

Enjoy